# Weird output when trying to list all customers in Stripe using php

Tags: php, database, list, stripe-payments

I created a database customers.txt where are saved all my created customers in Stripe. Now I want to list all the customers. This is my code in php for listing customers.

```html
   $e= \Stripe\Customer::all(array(
        'limit' => 3
       

     ));
   
echo $e;


    }
```

But the output is weird:

IMAGE: 
[image]

Can someone help me to list the customers?

Now I have got my JSON and run this:

```html
$e=\Stripe\Customer::all(array(
    "limit"=>10

 ));

$customers=json_decode($e,true);
var_dump($customers);
```

I get just NULL response!

Comment: source and email are not valid parameters to the list customer api, https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_customers

Comment: @MatthewArkin I edited the post.

Comment: so $e->data is an array of customers, $e->data[0] would be a customer object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That output is not wyrd, it's a Stripe JSON string. standing for **J**ava**s**cript **O**bject **N**otation ([website](http://www.json.org/)).

There's a lot of questions on Stackoverflow about JSON so ask things such as [How to convert JSON string into a PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511821/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array). 
Also Stripes own documentation (which is very good), states:

> JSON is returned by all API responses, including errors, although our API libraries convert responses to appropriate language-specific objects.

from [the Stripe Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php)

Edit:
You can read [A useful question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858448/converting-object-to-json-and-json-to-object-in-php-library-like-gson-for-java) about turning a JSON string into an object and vice versa

**So now you know what JSON is**

Using it to get a PHP customer object. (revised)

```
$e // customer JSON of all customers.  
$customers = $e->__toArray(true);
//$customers = json_decode($e);
```

And then process the array `$customers` as you need to in your applicaton.

**NOTE:**

The value of `$customers` or `$customersArray` will be an Object or a String data type so you need to treat the appropriately, and they will not display with `echo` because echo is a string output function, so you need to use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` to display these values -in their raw form- on the screen.

**EDIT TWO**

Recommended that from your screenshot that you format the API response from Stripe into an Array of Objects. This can be done by following [this Stack Overflow Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27364648/3536236).

Please review my revised code above.

Comment: So is this the right way to list the customers in Stripe? Except the convertion to php array?

Comment: Once you've got the JSON you can then use a `json_decode` function to turn the JSON data into a PHP object (or several). I will update my answer....

Comment: Now I'm taking blank response after the convertion.

Comment: Because you're trying to echo an array, instead use `print_r()` or `var_dump()`. Also please do not change the question but add additions to it, future people will be confused as you have not shown your JSON screen shot, which I used to answer your original query. @user6591546

Comment: No worries @user6591546 . If that solved your issue then you can tick the tick next to my answer, and possibly give a +1 (up arrow) too. :-)

Comment: it now outputs NULL eventhough are customers in database

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336921/stripe-api-json-returns-null . You need to research a lot of Qs on SO as there are many regarding stripe. By the looks of your image your JSON should be formed into an **Object** rather than an array.(remove the `true`)

Comment: My database is .txt.

Comment: I don't see how that relates to the JSON output.

Comment: I have updated my answer with further references and another approach to solving this issue.

Comment: I voted your question but I cant tick it. It doesnt solve my problem.